# ¿A qué se debe el cambio de tamaño en mi App? ¿Qué tamaño toma una App cuando es subida a Play Store?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

Tengo una App ya subida a Play Store. En la ficha me dice que la misma tiene un tamaño de `2 MB`.

Estoy ahora preparando una actualización de la misma y probándola en mi dispositivo , instalándola mediante cable USB.

Revisando la información de la misma en el dispositivo, noto que ha cambiado considerablemente de tamaño:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí se ve, en el cuadro verde, a la izquierda un valor preocupante de `44 MB` que no sé exactamente a qué corresponde. Luego a la derecha, se ve un valor de `16.06 MB`.

Si voy a los detalles de la App (recién instalada), me dice que los `16.06MB` corresponden a `Almacenamiento`, distribuidos así: *Tamaño de la aplicación: 15.97MB / Datos del usuario: 77.82KB / Caché: 8.44KB*  y de los otros `44 MB` no dice nada (por el símbolo gris que aparece a la izquierda interpreto que son 44MB en memoria, lo cual no sabría tampoco qué significa).

Cabe decir que borré la App y que la instalé totalmente nueva mediante el cable USB.

Revisando la carpeta del proyecto, ésta tiene un tamaño de `2.55MB`, algo más o menos coherente con el tamaño que dice Play Store que tiene la App subida.

En esta nueva versión yo he agregado algunas cosas, pero no creo que eso justifique ese aumento de tamaño:

- Librería GSon
- Algunas clases del modelo de datos
- Algunos archivos de texto muy pequeños
- Un archivo JSON muy pequeño
- Varias `Activity` nuevas (unas 7)
- Librería Firebase (y sincronización en tiempo real). Debo decir que actualmente hay pocos datos de prueba en Firebase como para alcanzar siquiera 16MB.

Mi duda es, ¿la App tendrá un tamaño de `44MB` o de `16MB` o de `44MB+16MB` cuando la suba a Play Store o bien este tamaño es algo normal cuando se depura mediante USB y el tamaño de la App será el que tiene el folder que la contiene (2MB aproximadamente)? Quiero saberlo por si debo hacer alguna limpieza antes de subirla a Play Store.

¿A qué equivale el valor de `44 MB` realmente?

Estuve leyendo sobre [App Bundles](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle), pero no encontré respuestas a mi duda. Hice un `Clean Project` y nada cambió.

Comment: eso mismo me ha sucedido, la mia ha pasado de 4 a 16 mb

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez ¿en prueba o ya subida a Play Store? ¿estás probándola vía USB también?

Comment: Cree una apk firmada y esa instale en los dispositivos,es una app privada

Comment: Suponiendo, aunque no es mi área (prefiero las bridge o híbridas), se puede deber al hecho de que la aplicación ha de tener en modo de depuración o desarrollador algunos componentes que son subidos junto con la apk instalada para poder realizar la respectiva depuración; si puedes firmar la apk como si fueses a lanzar una app a producción, luego la pasas a tu celular (descarga e instalas) dandolo los permisos suficientes para que pueda instalarla desde un tercero; prueba y nos comentas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Es normal observar un tamaño mayor al .apk cuando tienes por ejemplo una aplicación que descarga y almacena información ya sea en base de datos, preferencias o archivos.

Como ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si a esta aplicación le eliminamos los datos, obtenemos la medida original al instalar la aplicación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Pero ahora **¿por qué nuestro .apk tiene una medida y al ser instalado aumenta su tamaño?**

En realidad se debe a que el .apk en realidad es un archivo compreso. Por esta razón al ser instalado aumenta su tamaño. Como prueba puedes cambiar la extensión de .apk a .zip:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al convertir a .zip puedes extraer los archivos compresos en el archivo .apk  y la medida de todos estos archivos es similar a la aplicación instalada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Caramba, qué bueno. Recientemente me encontré con esta casuística y no sabía el porqué.